# Блок не отзывается на нажатие

Tags: javascript, html

Я еще новичок в js по этому не могу справиться со следующей проблемой: эта строка создает элемент в маркированном списке.

```js
function addLi(nameGroup, classGroup) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("item");
    var div = document.createElement("li");
    div.setAttribute('class', classGroup);
    div.setAttribute('id', 'item');
    div.innerHTML = nameGroup.toString();
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(div);
}
```

Но после создания элемента я не могу привязать к нему событие `click()`. Когда добавил в самом html такой же элемент и потом создал еще новый, то первый реагировал на нажатия, а второй нет(

Я уже пробовал разные способы добавления: insertBefore, appendChild

Comment: `div.setAttribute('id', 'item');` этой строкой вы добавляете айди элементу. если двум элементам добавить одинаковый айди, то второй реагировать не будет, ибо айди должен быть уникальным у каждого элемента.

Comment: @lexxl спасибо, сейчас попробую. Слушай, а какая есть альтернатива или как можно на js написать: `$('.sidebar__items').find(li)`?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar__items li')` - querySelectorAll возвращает список элементов в пределах документа (поиск осуществляется в пределах указанного элемента) которые соответствуют указанной группе селекторов.

Comment: @lexxl поменял `div.setAttribute('id', classGroup);` но все равно не отзывается на нажатия (`classGroup` постоянно меняется). Обращаюсь по классу `item`.
Может проблема в том как я добавил новый блок на страницу? Я js когда ищет его, то попросту не видит?

Comment: @АртемГолинка ну да, когда ты создаешь новый элемент на нем нет никаких слушателей, повесь на него так же `div.addEventListener('click', addLi)` внутри своего метода после `elem.parentNode.appendChild(div);`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не вешаешь обработчик после добавления нового контейнера. Поэтому и не вызывается событие `click`.

Добавь в самый конец своего метода подписку на событие:

```
div.addEventListener('click', addLi)
```

Тогда ново-созданный div будет смотреть на тот же метот, кто его создал, и вызывать его.